# Jquery adding [ ] characters after arrays sent in requests

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, cherrypy

I have a jquery-based client making requests to my server. Server is based on Cherrypy (python).

In queries where the client sends an array, my requests urls seems to be polluted with characters '[]' at the end, I presume  by jquery. For instances:

```
this.setParameters = function(params) {
    let reqUrl = this.apiPath() + "setParameters";
    let reqParams = {};
    let requiredParams = ['sessionKey'];
    let optionalParams = ['resolutions', 'dimensions'];

    this.fillRequiredParams(reqParams, requiredParams, params);
    this.fillOptionalParams(reqParams, optionalParams, params);
     console.log('API.setParameters sending these :', reqParams);
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        dataType: 'json',
        url: reqUrl,
        data:reqParams,
        success: function(data, textStatus, request) {
            if(typeof params.success === 'function') {
                params.success(data);
            }
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            console.log('setParameters - error', textStatus);
            if(typeof params.error === 'function') {
                params.error(textStatus, errorThrown);
            }
        }
    });
};


this.fillOptionalParams = function(reqParams, optionalParams, params) {
    $.each(optionalParams, function() {
        let optParamName = this;
        if(params[optParamName] !== undefined) {
            reqParams[optParamName] = params[optParamName];
        }
    });
};
```

Results in the console client-side:

[image]

And then if I log things as received on the server-side (those are received as **kwargs in the Cherrypy endpoint, hence the dict_items, but all that is managed by CP itself):

```
SERVER.setParameters : dict_items([('resolutions[]', ['0.00009999999999999999', '0.00009999999999999999']), ('dimensions[]', ['0.0027', '0.0027']))
```

The root cause of the problem however has to be on the client because the parameters names as sent by the client contain those pesky '[]' at the end of each.

What I would like:

- Send those parameters as array without the [] characters appended (e.g. I don't want to have to split them up client-side before sending)
- Ideally so I can just parse them directly in python with the json lib and not have to do messy string-parsing for every argument....

Thanks!

Comment: I suspect you may need to stringify your array. What do you see in console?

Comment: No, it's not jq. If you create a regular form with pure HTML, the browser will do the same.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow you @webKnjaZ. Could you clarify a little?

Comment: It works this way by design.

Comment: @webKnjaZ they called it stackoverflow.com not because charade.com was already taken, but because the point is to provide clear answers to questions. JS isn't really my stack. Any idea how I can tweak this to have an easily parsable form in python on server-side?

Comment: My point is that you probably shouldn't change it. But if you want to control the format of data struct, convert everything into JSON and send it in the HTTP request body

Comment: AH! now that does make a lot of sense to me. Thanks a bunch!